# Perform calculations on number ranges mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot, range

Is it possible to work with number ranges in MySQL and if so, what would be the best way to accomplish the following.

1. I have a range in two table columns.

```
+------+-------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Action |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1    | 100   | Add    |
+------+-------+--------+
```

2. Next, I wish to subtract the range [60,65], subtract the range [20, 40] and add the range [200,210]. So I add these records to my table.

```
+------+-------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Action |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1    | 100   | Add    |
| 60   | 65    | Subtr  |
| 20   | 40    | Subtr  |
| 200  | 210   | Add    |
+------+-------+--------+
```

3. Lastly, I would like to retrieve the ranges that are left. The query should return something like this.

```
+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2  |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 19    |
| 41   | 59    |
| 66   | 100   |
| 200  | 210   |
+------+-------+
```

**Extra Info**

- The business logic prevents overlapping ranges
- The business logic prevents subtracting ranges that aren't in the available ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Action1 = 'Add' THEN col1 
             WHEN Action1 = 'Subtr' THEN col1 + 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END) col1, 
       (CASE WHEN Action2 = 'Add' THEN col2 
             WHEN Action2 = 'Subtr' THEN col2 - 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END) col2
FROM (SELECT CEILING(RowNum / 2) AS RowId, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum % 2 = 1 THEN col ELSE 0 END) AS col1, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum % 2 = 1 THEN Action ELSE '' END) AS Action1,         
             MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum % 2 = 0 THEN col ELSE 0 END) AS col2, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum % 2 = 0 THEN Action ELSE '' END) AS Action2
      FROM (SELECT (@id:=@id+1) AS RowNum, col, Action 
            FROM (SELECT col1 AS col, Action 
                  FROM tableA 
                  UNION 
                  SELECT col2 AS col, Action 
                  FROM tableA 
                 ) AS A, 
                 (SELECT @id:=0) AS B
            ORDER BY col
           ) AS A
      GROUP BY RowId
     ) AS A;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87b4af/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
|------|------|
|    1 |   19 |
|   41 |   59 |
|   66 |  100 |
|  200 |  210 |
```

**::Explanation::**

As you see in my query that first I had fetched all start-range and end-range in single column with its action type and then given a row number for each records to transpose that data in two columns because I want to create an inner table as below:

```
| ROWID | COL1 | ACTION1 | COL2 | ACTION2 |
|-------|------|---------|------|---------|
|     1 |    1 |     Add |   20 |   Subtr |
|     2 |   40 |   Subtr |   60 |   Subtr |
|     3 |   65 |   Subtr |  100 |     Add |
|     4 |  200 |     Add |  210 |     Add |
```

And in last I had used CASE statement to generate specific output.

Comment: not working if we add one more value in table `(205,215,'Subtr')`

Comment: @tzafar This is not a problem in my case. The application logic prevents adding a 'Subtr' row whith a range outside the available ranges. I.E. It's impossible to subtract range [205 - 215] because the available ranges go from [1 - 210].

Comment: @Saharsh This is a brilliant working solution! But could you explain the steps in your query a bit further? I don't want to just copy/paste everything without understanding what's going on.

Comment: What about adding (205, 207, 'Add')  that does not seem to work  in the fiddle example

Comment: @danb The business logic will prevent the adding of overlapping ranges. Your situation is not a problem in my case.

Comment: @UwConcept   OK. Perhaps you can add that to you question.

Answer (score 0):

MySql  does not have any features to specifically handle this. The easiest and most efficient way to do this is to create a stored procedure.  Create a cursor to iterate over the rows  in the Col1, Col2,Action table (lets call that the action table).  Then keep  a temp table that keeps the current set of ranges.  For a substract command you can generate another cursor that gets only the rows in the tmp table that needs  to be updated.  For example:

```
select * from tmpResults where (action.col1 <= tmpResults.col1 <= action.col2)
or (action.col1 <= tmpResults.col2 <=  action.col2)
```

Then delete the rows that apply and add either the one or  two rows that get added.

When adding rows, I am assuming you can have overlaps, but not duplicates?

In any case, using a stored procedure  is the  approach  I recommend.

Comment: I'm not really keen on using cursors. Don't they use up a lot of memory? The solution provided by @Shaharsh Shah does exactly what I need.

Comment: If @Shaharsh solution works then that is a good  approach. I'm not sure it works on all inputs